# Sequelize hooks not triggering when updating records manually

Tags: javascript, node.js, postgresql, sequelize.js, sequelize-hooks

I am new to sequelize and RDBMS,
I have added sequelize hook as follows

```
bills.afterBulkUpdate((instance, options) => {
  console.log(instance);
});
```

I have questions here If I update any record in bills table manually(using DB script or query or triggers)
Do this update will trigger `bills.afterBulkUpdate` hook declared?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hooks (also known as callbacks or lifecycle events) are functions that are called before and after calls in sequelize are executed.

So as per your code, you are using `afterBulkCreate(name, fn)` ( [link](https://sequelize.readthedocs.io/en/v3/api/hooks/#afterbulkcreatename-fn) ) which is identified as  A hook that is run after creating instances in bulk.

It should work after trigger the hook, It depends on how you have declared and used in your code.

For more details on hooks you can see its official [documentation](https://sequelize.readthedocs.io/en/2.0/docs/hooks/)

Comment: My question is does this hook would be triggered if same table record updated/created with DB level triggers or script outside application.

Comment: It will trigger but as your full code is not available there so I have mentioned that It depends on how you have declared and used in your code. If you are following documentation so it will work